# Databinding enums to checkboxes C#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, enums

Does anyone know how one can data bind `enum` field which is a combination of ORed base `enum`?
Say I have

```
MyEnumType
{ 
    e1=0x1, 
    e2=0x2, 
    e3=0x4
}
```

and then I do

```
MyEnumType myEnum = MyEnumType.e1 | MyEnumType.e3
```

Then I would like to display a dialog box which can be used to set value of `myEnum`.
Right now I have a bunch of checkboxes each of which corresponds to a different value in `enum` type.
Depending on what is checked I cycle through them and so on.  No data binding done, all is manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for `FlaggedEnumEditor`. It will be a good enough example to understand the concept.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a helper class (view model) that:

- Had properties called E1, E2, etc
- The class will implement IPropertyChanged
- The set method of each property will update the underlying value, the get method will read from the underlying value.
- Whenever the underlying value is changed, you will need to work out which properties have changed and call IPropertyChanged correctly.

Then just databind the check boxes to the properties.

**However if I had more than one such enum, I would start looking for solution that did not need me to write so much code.**